# Commands for cyrillic letters in TeX

Tags: cyrillic

The simplest and the most important cyrillic thing is nowhere to be found. I need a list of cyrillic letters and commands to get them in TeX. Most of them you just type Latin letter, but some need special commands. AMS used to have that list, but it is nowhere to be found now.

Comment: you can just type in cyrillic if you prefer. You don't have to use ascii commands.

Comment: Thanks David, sounds good, except that I would have to learn what keys of my qwerty are for what Russian alphabet letters. That is a gigantic task, way more complicated than having a list of those cyrillic letters in front of me, when I type.

Comment: the documentation for the old ams wncr fonts is where it always was: `texdoc amsfonts`  section 6  but that isn't the easiest way to typeset cyrillic these days

Comment: but note that if you use the wncr fonts the characters are not just entered using latin leters they ar encoded as latin ascii leters and just "look" like cyrillic, so for example will cut and paste as ascii from the pdf.

Comment: That's it, the table that I need is on page 17. That table is as easy as pie. Today I needed the "turned E" and forgot how to use it. You simply do \'E and you get it. What "easier" method do you know of? The own you suggested is infinitely more difficulty as I said because Russian alphabet layout is incongruous with qwerty. I am using ordinary TeX, with AMS fonts when needed, not LaTeX.

Comment: I think it would be useful to post that table here, as an answer to my question, but I have it in PDF format and it may be that se does not support that format, only image files?

Answer (score 1):

the documentation for the old ams wncr fonts is where it always was:

```
texdoc amsfonts
```

or https://texdoc.org/serve/amsfndoc/0

Section 6:

[image]

but that isn't the easiest, or recommended way to typeset cyrillic these days

note that if you use the wncr fonts the characters are not just entered using latin leters they are encoded in the latin ascii font positions, so for example will cut and paste as ascii from the pdf.

You do not need an ascii transliteration or ascii commands these days

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
Привіт Світ
\end{document}
```

Produces

[image]